# Confused why script does not exit

Tags: bash, shell, subshell, process-substitution

I have this script verbatim:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash


handle_json(){
  while read line; do
    cat <<EOF
{"@json-stdio":true,"value":{"mark":"$1","v":"$line"}}
EOF
    done;
}

( echo; echo; echo 'du results:'; exit 0 ) > >(handle_json foo);

echo "zoom"
```

when I execute it, I get this:

[image]

I have to manually kill it with ctrl-C since it won't exit on it's own.

All I am trying to do is send the stdout of the subshell to the bash function so it JSON stringify the output (don't worry about escaping special chars for now).

Anybody know why this script doesn't exit on it's own?

**UPDATE**:

this actually does what I want it to do:

```
( echo; echo; echo 'du results'; ) |  handle_json 'foo';

echo "zoom"
```

the above uses the pipe operator instead of redirection/process substition. I never expected the pipe operator to work here. Can someone explain why/how it works?

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't exit? It looks that bash is simply printing its prompt before the `>(...)` subshell has exited, which is to be expected with subshells which are run asynchronously. Press 'Enter' instead of '^C'.

Comment: ... or put a `sleep 1` at the end (just a debugging aid, not a good solution, as that's a race condition) to make sure the subshell finishes first. Then you'll see the prompt after 1s as expected.

Comment: _Don't_ post images of text. Just copy-paste the text instead, it makes it easier for others to read it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, your script *did* exit; it's just that the process substitution finished running and printing in the background after the outer shell printed its prompt.

A way to avoid this would be to simply pipe into your function instead of using `> >(...)`:

```
( echo; echo; echo 'du results:'; exit 0 ) | handle_json foo
```

This works because, when writing `cmd1 | cmd2`, the two commands are started in parallel, with the standard output of `cmd1` connected to the standard input of `cmd2`, *and* bash waits for both to have completed to consider the pipeline complete.

In contrast, `cmd1 > >(cmd2)` does nearly the same, except that bash does not wait for `cmd2` to complete before going on with further commands (in this case, printing "zoom" and then exiting, letting the interactive bash print its prompt): if, by chance, `cmd2` takes significantly more time to complete than `cmd1`, then the kind of surprising race condition you observed happens.

Comment: thanks, I updated the OP right after I saw this answer! why does this work and the redirection/process substitution behave so strangely?

Comment: I will update my answer to address this additional question.